# Linking two libraries that uses openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, qt4, libcurl

- platform: GNU/Linux Debian Etch 32b
- libcurl 7.37.1
- qt 4.8.1
- openssl 0.9.8

Above is a schema with the dependencies of my app (only the one involved in this question)

```
+-----------------+
| application     |
+-----------------+
| libcurl | libqt |
+-----------------+
| libssl          |
+-----------------+
```

My c++ application is based on qt 4.8.1 but for some http/network operation we use libcurl
Both libs are compiled with the ssl support
Im facing a really strange error scenario:

- Object1 runs a **curl_easy_perform()** to an https site. The call reports an error. The curl_error_buffer contains:

> error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: none

- Later on Object2 calls **QSslSocket.write()**

This second call generates a QTcpError.
The error string reported by the QSslSocket is:

```
TCP Error: Error while reading: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file, error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Both objects live in the same application thread.

Tracing the application behavior with gdb it seems like:

- The **X509_load_cert_crl_file** call is performed inside the curl_easy_perform()
- When the method **QSslSocket.write()** is called, the function: **X509_load_cert_crl_file** *is not called* netherless the SSL stack returns to the qt network stack the above error.

My idea is that the SSL lib state is somehow global (i.e. errno) and/or shared between two library (qt and libcurl) and performing the QSslSocket.write() we got the error state previously set by the libcurl call.

- Does it make any sense?
- I'm I using the libcurl the wrong way, so that it is leaving the ssl connection in some inconsistent state?

Please note that the qt write method actually perform internally a write AND a read from the socket. After that the state of ssl is checked with **SSL_get_error**

(Qt code here: https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/v4.8.1/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp#L1140)

Comment: rebuilt both with the same ssl?

Comment: @deW1: not sure I get the question right: you are asking if I built both libs using the same libssl? If so: yes, we build both libcurl and qt linking the system openssl libs